# How to process an open file using MapReduce framework

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a file that get aggregated and written into HDFS. This file will be opened for an hour before it is closed. Is it possible to compute this file using MapReduce framework, while it is open? I tried it but it's not picking up all appended data. I could query the data in HDFS and it available but not when done by MapReduce. Is there anyway I could force MapReduce to read an open file? Perhaps customize the FileInputFormat class?

Answer (score 0):

You can read what was physically flushed. Since close() makes the final flush of the data, your reads may miss some of the most recent data regardless how you access it (mapreduce or command line). 
As a solution I would recommend periodically close the current file, and then open a new one (with some incremented index suffix). You can run you map reduce on multiple files. You would still end up with some data missing in the most recent file, but at least you can control it by frequency of of your file "rotation".